# openUrl is not working in first attempt for mailto option in emulator in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

```
I have tried to open gmail using linking.openUrl - mailto option. I can open gmail in my real device with first attempt.But In emulator its not open in first attempt and if I click same link second time it open gmail.

I couldn't understand what could be the cause.

Sample code:

Linking.canOpenURL(url)
        .then(ok => {
          if (ok) {
            console.log(Linking.openURL(url));
            return Linking.openURL(url);
          } else {
            console.warn("can't open mailto: iOS sim doesn't support it");
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
```

Initially checking given url is valid or not. If valid try to open using openUrl concept

Comment: Ever get this figured out? I'm having the same problem.